# linked list iterator inner class-java

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, inner-classes

I am writing an iterator inner class that iterates through a list. Besides the remove method, I believe I have implemented all the methods of iterator correctly but I get an error saying "Bound mismatch: The type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter > of the type List.Node". I believe this has to with having Node> implements Iterable at the top of my code but I do not want to change that if unneeded. Any possible suggestions on what I should do?

```
public class List<T extends Comparable<L>> implements Iterable<L> {

    private class Node<N extends Comparable<N>> {
        private N data;
        private Node<N> next;
    }
    protected Node<L> head;


    public Iterator<L> iterator() {

        return new ListIterator<L>();

    }

    public class ListIterator<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterator<E> {

        private Node<E> N = (Node<E>) head; //"Bound mismatch: The type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <D extends Comparable<D>> of the type List<T>.Node<D>"

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (N.next != null);
        }

        public E next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            else {
                N = N.next;
                return N.data;
            }
        }

        public void remove() {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type parameter `N` is declared as

```
N extends Comparable<N>
```

ie. it has bounds. It must be `Comparable` to itself.

The type parameter `E` is declared as

```
E
```

ie. it has no bounds. It can be any type, but not necessarily a type that is `Comparable` to itself.

Therefore, you can't use `E` where an `N` is expected. Consider adding the same bounds as `N` to `E`.

Comment: Hmm, could I make E extend N then?

Comment: @Kracie You'd have to have `N` be available in `E`'s scope.

Comment: How would I do that? I don't think private/public matters for N as inner classes can see that regardless, I think

Comment: @Kracie Don't make your life difficult. Just declare the same bounds for `E` as `N`.

Comment: @Kracie No. [Read about generic type bounds here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) By its bounds, `N` is considered a `Comparable<N>`. Now, make `E` be `Comparable<E>`. It will have the same (and compatible) bounds. It can now be used where an `N` is required.

Comment: I think I've changed the bounds in my code above. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Kracie Please don't overwrite the code in your question. It makes our answers obsolete or wrong. Instead, add it after the existing code. I don't know what `L` is in your code, but `E` now has the same bounds as `N`, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You should reduce the number of generic types. Because the inner classes know the generic type of their parent class, you should simplify the Node and ListIterator class:

```
public class List<L extends Comparable<L>> implements Iterable<L> {
    private class Node {
        private L data;
        private Node next;
    }
    protected Node head;

    public Iterator<L> iterator() {

        return new ListIterator();

    }

    public class ListIterator implements Iterator<L> {

        private Node N = head;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (N.next != null);
        }

        public L next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            else {
                N = N.next;
                return N.data;
            }
        }

        public void remove() {

        }

    }
}
```